# Postfix from=<> Have I been hacked by a spammer?

Tags: email, postfix

mailq is showing a bunch of connection timeouts in deferred queue to addresses that look weird.

```
D1115234D9     3037 Thu Feb 25 11:01:38  MAILER-DAEMON
       (connect to mail.suchgt.top[63.143.32.55]:25: Connection timed out)
                                     Yacht.Rentals.Specials@wqkuy.suchgt.top

D7E46234B6     2992 Thu Feb 25 15:16:42  MAILER-DAEMON
      (connect to mail.bravepb.top[46.19.138.77]:25: Connection timed out)
                                     Diabetes-Video@dhbnv.bravepb.top

F10E2230E3     3003 Thu Feb 25 06:55:39  MAILER-DAEMON
     (connect to mail.refillu.top[199.115.97.43]:25: Connection timed out)
                                     Rachael-Ray@qhjkk.refillu.top

F34F223661     3219 Thu Feb 25 12:03:30  MAILER-DAEMON    
 (connect to nlwe9u1qq.manorby.download[8.41.46.184]:25: Connection refused)
                                     PrivateJetQuote@manorby.download

F3C0923133     3282 Thu Feb 25 06:55:14  MAILER-DAEMON
(lost connection with eschatological.gzgi.download[209.219.189.55] while receiving the initial server greeting)
                                            Cloud_Solution_Providers@gzgi.download

-- 969 Kbytes in 266 Requests.
```

When I track down one of these message ID's to try and see who is sending the message I get from=<>

grep "D7E46234B6" mail.log

```
Feb 25 15:16:42 c postfix/smtpd[11744]: D7E46234B6: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Feb 25 15:16:42 c postfix/cleanup[11733]: D7E46234B6: message-id=<dovecot-1456431382-649365-0@c.me.go>
Feb 25 15:16:42 c postfix/qmgr[2440]: D7E46234B6: from=<>, size=2992, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 25 15:16:42 c amavis[11668]: (11668-01) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, <> -> <Diabetes-Video@dhbnv.bravepb.top>, Message-ID: <dovecot-1456431382-649365-0@c.me.go>, mail_id: zbne-aplX4iS, Hits: 0.898, size: 2544, queued_as: D7E46234B6, 20276 ms
Feb 25 15:16:42 c postfix/smtp[11739]: A345D23687: to=<Diabetes-Video@dhbnv.bravepb.top>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=20, delays=0.01/0/0.06/20, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as D7E46234B6)
Feb 25 15:16:43 c postfix/smtp[11763]: D7E46234B6: to=<Diabetes-Video@dhbnv.bravepb.top>, relay=none, delay=0.24, delays=0.02/0/0.21/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.bravepb.top[46.19.138.77]:25: Connection refused)
Feb 25 15:26:27 c postfix/qmgr[2440]: D7E46234B6: from=<>, size=2992, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 25 15:26:58 c postfix/smtp[12339]: D7E46234B6: to=<Diabetes-Video@dhbnv.bravepb.top>, relay=none, delay=615, delays=585/0.23/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.bravepb.top[46.19.138.77]:25: Connection timed out)
Feb 25 15:41:27 c postfix/qmgr[2440]: D7E46234B6: from=<>, size=2992, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 25 15:41:57 c postfix/smtp[12959]: D7E46234B6: to=<Diabetes-Video@dhbnv.bravepb.top>, relay=none, delay=1515, delays=1484/0.12/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.bravepb.top[46.19.138.77]:25: Connection timed out)
Feb 25 16:11:27 c postfix/qmgr[2440]: D7E46234B6: from=<>, size=2992, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 25 16:11:58 c postfix/smtp[14279]: D7E46234B6: to=<Diabetes-Video@dhbnv.bravepb.top>, relay=none, delay=3316, delays=3284/0.11/31/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.bravepb.top[46.19.138.77]:25: Connection timed out)
Feb 25 17:11:28 c postfix/qmgr[2440]: D7E46234B6: from=<>, size=2992, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 25 17:11:58 c postfix/smtp[16763]: D7E46234B6: to=<Diabetes-Video@dhbnv.bravepb.top>, relay=none, delay=6915, delays=6885/0.1/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.bravepb.top[46.19.138.77]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Question: Is there a way to tell who is attempting to send these bogus emails so I can stop them? Does this attack look like an exploit from a php script, an open relay, a hacked e-mail account, or other?

After my research has failed, I am not sure where to turn for my next diagnostic step. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This would better fit on security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix doesn't have some cheatsheet as Exim "exim -Mvh or exim -Mvb". However, they do have something like http://www.postfix.org/BUILTIN_FILTER_README.html

I believe what you have just experience is "email spoofing". To make sure none authorize can't send email via your domain, add SPF Record to your DNS and DKIM on your server.

Comment: @user3642891, More basic than that is that is he simply running an open mail relay so anyone can connect and ask his server to forward mail to anywhere else.   An open mail relay is bad mojo so he mostly just needs to configure the server to only accept mail from within his own network if it is bound for elsewhere.  The SPF record just helps cut down on spam going to you.  It is much more important not to be a bot for spammers to flood everyone else on the Internet with spam.